# Debug keyboard/mouse issues after resume from sleep

Tags: linux, xorg, suspend, crash

When I try to resume after suspend the keyboard and mouse doesn't work (not even the tty1,tty2..) and the screen come out blank with just the moose pointer. I am trying to debug the problem and trying to see where to start. It might be just that the OS crashes and nothing happens.

Which log files should I look at to see if there's anything weird in my Xw settings?

Which user folders (`~/.kde4`) can I try replacing?

I know this might be a very specific issue, but a general outline of steps to debug would be nice!

OS: OpenSUSE 42.3, kde5.9, kernel 4.4

Comment: Devices failing after resume usually means problems with drivers, ACPI etc. Can you `ssh` in from another computer after resume, so you can look at `dmesg` etc.? Anything pointing to problems in the `dmesg` you see during boot?

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's video drivers issues. Look for problems that other people have had with the exact same graphics card. If you're using the free graphics driver, try the proprietary one, and vice versa (`radeon`/`fglrx`, `nouveau`/`nvidia`).

KDE is unrelated. There may be interesting logs in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and in the kernel logs, but if the computer crashes on resume it won't have had time to save any logs.